# Change title to small caps but not in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, small-caps

I want the title for the Acknowledgements page in my thesis to be in small caps. However, if I change it, it also changes in the table of contents. 
[image: ToC]

How can I avoid this? Especially, the roman page number in the ToC is in small caps too, even if on the page it is in normal small letters. What I would like is to have the entry for Acknowledgements look the same way that the entry for Abstract does. Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage]{article} 

\let\stdsection\section 
\renewcommand\section{\newpage\stdsection}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{center}
\section{\sc{Acknowledgements}} 
Thanks
\end{center}

\section{Abstract} 
Abstract text

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}
Blablabla

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the way in which you are using, why don't you just put `\section[Acknowledgements]{\sc{Acknowledgements}}`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\titleformat*` (from the `titlesec` package) can be used in the body of the document; using a grouping mechanism, you can keep the effect local. In the example below I wrapped the format definition inside a command using a group to modify the aspect of only the desired sectional unit:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage]{article} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newcommand\SpSection{%
  \titleformat*{\section}{\centering\scshape\Large}
}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begingroup
\SpSection
\section{Acknowledgements}
Thanks
\endgroup

\section{Abstract} 
Abstract text

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I do it this way, how can I set the fontsize of the small caps title to the "normal" title size?

Comment: @Helen I've updated my answer with a simplified version.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: What happens to `\noindent` within and after the group? You may want to allow the user to insert `\noindent` his/herself after the section heading. Or offer options for code before and after the section heading.

Comment: @AhmedMusa: you're right. I've updated my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: You've changed too much. I have illustrated what I meant in my solution.

Comment: @AhmedMusa: Then I guess I misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 4):

For this simple requirement, the `sectsty` package can be useful:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\newcommand\specialsection[2][\bfseries]{%
  \sectionfont{\normalfont#1}\section*{#2}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}
  \sectionfont{}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\specialsection[\centering\scshape]{Acknowledgements}
Thanks

\specialsection{Abstract}
Abstract text

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}
Blablabla

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a little more control you need to define your own macros. To define a sectioning command you can use:

```
\newcommand\prematter@sp[1]{% 
    %\refstepcounter{section}% we do not need to step up the counter
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}% generate toe entry
     {\protect\numberline{}\textsc{#1}}%
     \sectionmark{#1}% % add to running header
     {\clearpage\LARGE\centering\bfseries \MakeUppercase{#1}\par}%
     \@afterheading % prepare indentation handling
     \addvspace{\baselineskip}
     \@afterindentfalse % comment out if you want to indent first paragraph
  }
```

Then it is preferable to define an environment named say `\prematter`

```
\newenvironment{prematter}[1]{%
   \prematter@sp{#1}}
{}
```

Here is a full MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage]{book} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\prematter@sp[1]{% % Complex form:
%\refstepcounter{section}% % step counter/ set label
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}% % generate toe entry
{\protect\numberline{}\textsc{#1}}%
\sectionmark{#1}% % add to running header
{\clearpage\LARGE\centering\bfseries \MakeUppercase{#1}\par}%
\@afterheading % prepare indentation handling
\addvspace{\baselineskip}
}
\newenvironment{prematter}[1]%
{%
   \prematter@sp{#1}}
{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\frontmatter
\begin{prematter}{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1]
\end{prematter}
\begin{prematter}{Abstract} 
\lipsum[1]
\end{prematter}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\addcontentsline` and the starred version of `\section*`, like this:

```
\section*{\sc{Acknowledgements}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}%
```

But I wouldn't recommend applying formatting (like `\sc`) to the section heading, since the best advantage os LaTeX and friends over document editors is its capability of keeping format and content separated.

So, if you have a special "acknowledgments" section, you should define it in the preamble and call it in the text; a (not so) simple solution is to copy the `\section` definition from `article.cls` and redefine it to the expected behavior. Something like this:

```
\makeatletter% This is needed to allow usage of the @ character 
\newcommand{\acknowledgements}{%
%  First we need to redefine the \section command formatting
  \begingroup%  This is needed to avoid the redefinition of \section to interfere with subsequent sections
    \renewcommand\section{%                        _
      \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%             |   This comes form the definition of
      {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%           |   \section in article.cls
      {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%                          _|
      {\centering\normalfont\Large\scshape}}%           added \centering and \scshape
%    Then we create a macro that 
%      1. Creates a starred \acknowledgements with the title "acknowledgements"; and
%      2. adds the starred version of \acknowledgements to the toc
  \section*{Acknowledgements}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother% Turns @ back into a special char
```

For a more friendly control over sectioning commands, you can use the `titlesec` package, as I had mentioned in the prevous version of my answer, and as in **@Gonzalo Medina**'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53021/5872).

Comment: The thing is that I only want one of the titles to be in small caps. All the others should look normal.

Comment: henrique gave two answers (and blocks of code). The first one should only alter the formatting for a single section. The second one looks like a suggestion.

Comment: I just realized that it looks much better if I use `\textsc` instead of `\sc` and doesn't affect the page numbers in the ToC. So I just use that. With the first answer, in the ToC I get a page number that is by one lower than where the title of the section actually is (I have each section on a new page).

Comment: @Helen The first answer should have the command order reversed; I think that the `\addcontentsline` command should be **after** the `\section*` command.

Comment: @Helen, I have edited my answer to try to be more clear about separating content and fomatting; @JohnReed's absolutely right twice, particularly, about the order of `\addcontentsline` (my bad). Please notice @GonzaloMedina's answer for a solution with `titlesec`

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Gonzalo Medina's solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ltxkeys}
\makeatletter
\ltxkeys@declarekeys[KV]{spsection}[sps@]{%
  cmd/code before;
  cmd/code after;
  cmd/heading properties;
  cmd/heading type/section;
  cmd/heading text;
  bool/no heading no/true;
  cmd/label//
    \ifltxkeys@dec\else
      \ifx\\#1\\\@latexerr{Label can't be empty}\@ehd\fi
    \fi;

}
\robust@def*\spsection{\@testopt\@spsection{}}
\new@def\@spsection[#1]{%
  \saverestoresecnumdepth0%
  \usename{sps@no heading nofalse}%
  \ltxkeys@setkeys[KV]{spsection}{#1}%
  \csname sps@code before\endcsname
  \begingroup
  \ifboolFT{sps@no heading no}{}{%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}%
  }%
  \cptexpandsecond{\titleformat*}{%
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\noexpand
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      \csname\csname sps@heading type\endcsname\endcsname
    }{\expandcsnonce{sps@heading properties}}%
  }%
  \ifcsnnullFT{sps@heading text}{}{%
    \@@warning{Heading text was empty when calling \string\spsection}%
  }%
  \cptexpanded{\noexpand\usename{\expandcsnonce{sps@heading type}}%
    {\expandcsnonce{sps@heading text}}}%
  \endgroup
  \ifx\sps@label\@empty\else
    \label{\sps@label}%
  \fi
  \saverestoresecnumdepth{1}%
  \futurelet\next\doendcode@a
}
\robust@def*\doendcode@a{%
  \ifx\next\@sptoken
    \expandafter\doendcode@b
  \else
    \csname sps@code after\expandafter\endcsname
  \fi
}
\lowercase{\def\doendcode@b} {\usename{sps@code after}}
\robust@def*\saverestoresecnumdepth#1{%
  \ifcase#1\relax
    \edef\savedsecnumdepth{\the\c@secnumdepth}%
  \or
    \c@secnumdepth\savedsecnumdepth\relax
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% Tests
\begin{document}
\paperheight=5cm
\pagenumbering{roman}

\spsection[
  label              =sec:first,
  heading type       =section,
  heading text       =Acknowledgment,
  heading properties =\centering\scshape\Large,
  no heading no      =true,
  code before        =\noindent Last section is~\ref{sec:last}
                        on page~\pageref{sec:last}.,
  code after         =\noindent,
]
Thanks

\section{Abstract}
Abstract text.

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Test section}
Some text.
\newpage

\section{Another test section}
Some text.

\spsection[
  heading type       =subsection,
  heading text       =Test subsection,
  heading properties =\scshape\large,
  code before        =\endgraf\noindent First section is
                        on page~\pageref{sec:first}.,
  label              =sec:last
]

Some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah! Now I see what you meant; effectively, I misunderstood your comment to my answer. Nice solution, by the way.