# Center a single chapter heading

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, chapters

I want to have a **single** chapter heading centered. The other chapter headings should **not** be centered.

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}


\chapter*{\centering{single centered heading}}
\begin{center}

\lipsum

\end{center}

\chapter*{regular not centered heading}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: There probably is an official way to do this seems to work to `\chapter*{\makebox[1.0\linewidth]{single centered heading}}`.

Comment: You should check Yannis Lazarides' answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53034/5872

Comment: @Peter: Thanks, that works even better since it doesn't produce a warning (\centerline is a TeX not a LaTeX command).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
\chapter*{\centerline{single centered heading}}
```

works only for a single line. For two or more lines use `\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Overleaf complains about `\centerline`. This works for me:

```
\chapter*{\begin{center}single centered heading\end{center}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!