# How to get the special capitalized headings

Tags: sectioning, capitalization

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I did some searching and could not find an answer as it is hard to word the question without providing a picture. 
[image: MWE]

I was wondering how the author got the text to look like that under 1. INTRODUCTION, and 2. UNIVERSAL ENVELOPING ALGEBRAS?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The words you should search for are "small caps" and "headings". Take a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52998, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83001

Comment: Use `titlessec` and the `block` style for sections. Details in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

centred caps and small caps headings, look like `amsart` class to me.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
 \section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get it without using amsart? I would prefer not to change my enter document class.

Comment: @GabrielH yes of course see the links in the first comment which are various ways of customizing headings, I just posted this simple version as the image looks like amsart to me, and if you wanted that it's easier to specify `amsart` than something else that has to be customised.

Answer (score 3):

With `sectsty`, another way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering\normalfont\scshape}
%\allsectionsfont{\centering\normalfont\scshape}  % for all sectional levels
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \section{Introducton}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{Another Section}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution that uses all the tools of `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[textwidth=140mm, textheight=213mm, marginratio={4:6,5:7}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator\GL{\mathfrak{gl}}
\DeclareMathOperator\chr{char}
\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filcenter\scshape}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Let $ L $ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra over the field $ F $. By a finite-dimensional representation, we mean a Lie algebra homomorphism $ φ \colon L → \GL(V)$ for some vector space $ V $ with $ \dim V < ∞ $. When $ φ $ is injective, $ φ $ is said to be a \emph{faithful} representation. If $ L $ has a faithful representation, then we can view elements of $ L$ as matrices with entries in $ F $. It is natural to ask whether every finite dimensional Lie algebra can be concretely realized in this way. Ado [1] gave an affirmative answer when $ \chr(F) = 0$. The result was extended by Iwasawa [2] to cover the case $ \chr(F) = p $ for prime $ p $. We follow Fulton and Harris [3] to give the proof for the case $ \chr(F) = 0 $.

\section{Universal Enveloping Algebras}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont}{\thesection}{1em}{\centering\textsc{#1}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \section{Introducton}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{Another Section}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]